# Was "Via Regia" the original name of the "Via Nova Traiana"?

Tags: ancient-history, roman-empire, transportation, travel

This is a quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_Traiana_Nova):

> The Via Traiana Nova or Via Nova Traiana (Latin for 'Trajan's New
> Road'), *previously known as the Via Regia or King's Highway*, was an
> ancient Roman road built by Emperor Trajan in the province of Arabia
> Petraea, from Aqaba on the Red Sea to Bostra.

Unfortunately no references are given, so I cannot verify the claim that *the Via Nova Traiana was previously known as the Via Regia*. Can anyone help me find evidence or historical sources that verify this claim?

Comment: (Timelimit): Both roads were used by kings, many kings, not the same individuals if you see my point. So, both are also known as King’s Road (Via Regia). This may be the confusion.

Comment: In other words, the King’s Road (via Regia) for via Traiana and via nova Traiana are different roads, in Jordan and Italy, respectively. (Writing on an iPad is killing me, lol. So, I’ll stop here).

Comment: Wikipedia's description might be a bit misleading. The King's Highway was an ancient caravan route from Egypt to Mesopotamia. Trajan built a *new* road on the same path, and gave his name to it. So the *Roman* road wasn't rbrt called the King's Highway, but it's a bit of a difference without distinction. Anyway, while there was no footnote on that sentence, this is actually mentioned in the reference Wikipedia listed for the article: *Rome's Eastern Trade: International Commerce and Imperial Policy 31 BC - AD 305*.

Comment: @Semaphore I understand that according to Wikipedia Trajan's road was built on the ancient King's highway (so essentially it is the same route), my question is, is there is any evidence for that? According to wikipedia it was previously known by the Romans as Via Regia, I would like to see a source for that claim.

Comment: Any why are there three votes to close this? Is there anything wrong with my question? It is very clear, and very on topic for this site.

Comment: @Semaphore just for the record, I did a quick search on that book you referenced for Via Regia or King's highway, but it yielded nothing.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I edited the title, is it better now?

Comment: I think that is much better; we'll see if it halts the closevotes.

Comment: @Bach - Sorry, no time to write answer. Here’s your reference, with context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Highway_(ancient)#Classical_antiquity

Comment: @JAsia how does this help?

Comment: @Bach -  I thought you were asking about this old road/highway.  That link merely discusses the history of this ancient road, before Trajan extended/improved it with military forts. Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @JAsia right, but I am looking for a source to verify this. The link you pointed out is missing references as well, so it's of no use to me.